# A simple C XML parser

Tags: c, xml

I need to read an XML formatted document from a C program and extract from it the elements and their values. For example in the following code:

```xml
<user name="Mark">
    <param name="Age" value="21"/>
    <param name="Country" value="NL"/>
</user>
```

I need to extract: `name = Mark`, `Age = 21` and `Country = NL`.

Up until today I've been doing this parsing manually which is a pain.

I don't care whether the file a "proper XML" or all that, I don't care about DTD's or other standard XML requirements. I just need to read and parse the values.

Does anyone know of a library other than lib eXpat to do this or code to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: When asking for libraries, you may wish to mention your platform, as libraries can be platform-specific.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mini-XML looks promising

http://www.minixml.org/

Answer (score 8):

[Libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/)

Comment: thanks, I already checked this and 1) it took me forever to understand what they wanted from me (in order to make it work) and 2) it complains that I don't have a DTD and that my file is not properly formatted. so, not a good solution.

Comment: I was thinking something more along the lines of http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/data-misc/xml/article.php/c4549

Comment: It shouldn't require a DTD, but it does require that the XML is well-formed -- i.e. that the start/end tags match up and that there are no illegal characters and that there is one and only root element. If your input is not well formed, maybe you should fix it. If you don't require your input to be well formed XML, but just something xml-ish, then you can easily write your own parser: Just search for the "<" & ">" chars to break it into pieces and then parse each piece. A lot of the complexity of an XML parser is because it has to parse any generalized XML into a specific internal model.

Comment: Don’t. Never ever try and write your own XML parser and never ever try and parse XML with a string splitter. You will have encoding and escaping issues. You will have interoperability issues. You will have security issues. Use one of the proven, tested and established libraries for your platform, expat or libxml2, for example, like many of the other comments here suggest.

Answer (score 6):

The [Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) parser is the best I've come across - I use it in my C++ code in preference to the various C++ parsers - but it is written in C. Very easy to use and embed in your application. So I don't see why in your question you say:

> (other than lib eXpat)

do you have something against it?

Comment: I indeed, I would definitely choose expat considering the given requirements. The only reason not to use it in this case that I can think of is if the poster has no grasp of creating data structures from SAX events and thus needs a DOM?

Comment: No, i don't have anything against it, in fact I am using it on another project, however it's big, and for what I need more complex than what i need. so, as i very clearly pointed in my question, I won't have expat as a solution

Comment: @Jessica You must have your own private definition of the word "big" - Expat is about as small an XML parser as you are going to get. Specifically, it is smaller than Mini-XML.

Comment: where can i get to learn about xml parsing using expat in C windows platform?

Answer (score 4):

How about Mini-XML?  It's lightweight, works with gcc, is ANSI-C compatible...

http://www.minixml.org/index.php

According to the documentation, to search for specific nodes would be as simple as:

```
/* Find the first "a" element */
    node = mxmlFindElement(tree, tree, "a",
                           NULL, NULL,
                           MXML_DESCEND);
```

Once you get the node, you can manipulate it according to your requirements.

Comment: thanks, i already posted this (see my own answer to the question)

Answer (score 1):

If C++ is OK then you might try [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/). I've been using it for a few years and it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider [miniML-Parser](https://github.com/kiishor/miniML-Parser), a simple and tiny XML parser library in C.

- Unlike other XML parser it is extremely easy to use. You need to call only one API to parse your XML data.
- It is a validating parser. It validates the syntax of XML data and also extracts the content of XML data.

In order to parse and extract the content from XML data you need to provide some information to the parser. for example XML element name, its child elements, attributes, content type etc. Parser uses *`xs_element_t`* structure to hold all these properties of XML data

In your example, you have 2 XML elements "user" and "param". *user* is a root element and *param* is a child element. Attribute "name" and "value" holds the content. In order to extract these content, you need to specify the content type and target address to store the content.

Example of *xs_element_t* for your XML data.

```
const xs_element_t user_root =
{
    .Name.String = "user",                 //!< name of XML element
    .Name.Length = 4,                      //!< Length of name
    
    .Attribute_Quantity = 1,               //!< Number of attributes of this element
    .Attribute          = attributes,      //!< Address of structure containing attributes

    .Child_Quantity = 1,                   //!< Number of child elements
    .Child          = &param_element,      //!< Address of structure holding child elements
};

const xs_element_t param_element =
{
    .Name.String = "param",                //!< name of XML element
    .Name.Length = 5,                      //!< Length of name

    .Attribute_Quantity = 2,               //!< Number of attributes of this element
    .Attribute          = attributes,      //!< Address of structure containing attributes    
};

//! Holds properties of attributes
const xs_attribute_t attributes[] =
{
    [0].Name.String = "name",           //!< Name of XML attribute
    [0].Name.Length = 4,                //!< Length of attribute name

    [0].Target.Type = EN_STATIC,        //!< Target address type is static.
    [0].Target.Address = &name,         //!< Target address offset from the parent target address
    [0].Content.Type   = EN_STRING,     //!< Content type is string.             

    [1].Name.String = "value",          //!< Name of XML attribute
    [1].Name.Length = 4,                //!< Length of attribute name

    [1].Target.Type = EN_STATIC,        //!< Target address type is static.
    [1].Target.Address = &value,        //!< Target address offset from the parent target address
    [1].Content.Type   = EN_STRING,     //!< Content type is string.             
};
```

> Note: Above structure is not complete. I have omitted some of the structure members to keep the example simple.

To parse xml data then call *parse_xml()* and pass address of *user_root* (root element) and XML data.

```
parse_xml(&user_root, xml_data, NULL);
```

You can also registers a callback function in the xs_element_t structure to get callback whenever parser encounters element/tag during parsing.

for further details refer https://github.com/kiishor/miniML-Parser

> Disclosure: I'm author of this miniML-Parser